# List losing an element somewhere between 2 points, when nothing is being done to that list in that area

Tags: python, list

```
  print liveCoords                                      # displays [(0,0),(1,0),(2,0)]
  if population > 3 or population < 2:
      if (j,i) in liveCoords:
          try:
              del liveCoords2[liveCoords2.index((j,i))]
          except:
              pass
  elif population == 3:
      if (j,i) in liveCoords:
          pass
      else:
          liveCoords2.append((j,i))
  print liveCoords                                       # displays [(1,0),(2,0)]
```

My question is not about how to do something specific, it is how my list liveCoords could possible be changed between those 2 points, from what I can see, nothing is being done that could possibly alter liveCoords, yet it is being altered.

Comment: You haven't given us the values of i, j and population.

Comment: Can you make an executable example that shows the error?  My guess at this point is that `liveCoords2` is referring to the same object as `liveCoords`.  If that is the case, the `del liveCoords2[...]` would also affect `liveCoords`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create `liveCoords2` with the line `liveCoords2 = liveCoords`?  If so then they are both references to the same list, so adding or removing elements in `liveCoords2` would affect `liveCoords` as well.

If this is the case, then changing the assignment to `liveCoords2 = list(liveCoords)` or `liveCoords2 = liveCoords[:]` would fix this.  Note that both of these methods will create a shallow copy, if any elements in `listCoords` are mutable objects then `listCoords2` will have references to the same objects as `listCoords`, this should be fine for your current code but if you do end up needing to create a deep copy you can use the [copy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#module-copy) module:

```
import copy
liveCoords2 = copy.deepcopy(liveCoords)
```

Comment: I did create liveCoords2 like that, I tried changing it to all of your suggested alternatives, but sadly to the same result

Comment: @buckley.w.david - Interesting, I would have expected that to fix it.  Please edit your question with the code from where you create `liveCoords2` up to what you currently have and I (or someone else) may be able to spot the issue.

Comment: I found another point at which I do a similar thing again, I changed that and now the problem seems to be resolved. Thank you.